# Strange WordPress behavior whe I try to open an article

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am developing, on my local web server, a simple Word Press blog but I am finding a strange behavior

After that I have post a new article, it appear in homepage but, when I click on its title to open it, appear the following error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /wordpress/archives/56 was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I have the same problem also if I try to click on the related category icon of the article or if I click on the "add your comment" icon

If I don't use Permalink seems work fine !!! So the problem is related to the Permalin....

Why? some ideas to solve using Permalink?

Comment: check when you are updating permalinks then  many time its showing  htaccess code for the file  if that  use that code in you htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vickey says above, you need to update your .htaccess file to use permalinks.

If your Wordpress installation is inside a folder called 'wordpress' inside your root folder then it will be similar to this;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```